# BeautifulSoup - find table with specified class on Wikipedia page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a table in a Wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup and for some reason I don't get the table.
Can anyone tell why I don't get the table?

my code:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Historic_Landmarks_in_Louisiana'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')

tab=soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
print tab
```

prints: None

Comment: can you specify clearly the modules you are using? where do `requests.get `come from?

Comment: @DJJ `requests.get` is from the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You shouldn't use `jquery-tablesorter` to select against in the response you get from requests because it is dynamically applied after the page loads. If you omit that, you should be good to go.

```
tab = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"})
```